# A slight extension of Sacks theorem

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, lo.logic, computability-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Sacks proves the following theorem first.

> **Theorem 1**: If $\alpha$ is a countable admissible ordinal, then there is a real $x$ so that $\omega_1^x=\alpha$.

Anyone knows who proves the following slight extension of the theorem?

> **Theorem 1'**: If $\alpha$ is a countable admissible ordinal and $z\not\in L_{\alpha}$, then there is a real $x$ so that $\omega_1^x=\alpha$ but $z\not\in L_{\alpha}[x]$.

Clearly Theorem 1' follows from Friedman-Jensen's application of Barwise compactness plus omitting type theorem. But for the other proofs such as Sacks's and Steel's, the extension seems not an immediate conclusion of their methods.

Comment: In Theorem 3.19 of Sacks paper, there is a minimal pair constructed. Then Theorem 1' follows from it.

Comment: Hi Liang.  For both Sacks's and Steel's forcing proofs of Sacks's Theorem 1, if $p$ is a condition and $\tau$ is a ranked term for a subset of $\omega$, then $p$ forces $n\in\tau$ is a ranked property of $p$ and $\tau$.  The verification for Sacks forcing uses what Sacks called "local genericity." The verification for Steel forcing uses Steel's Retagging Lemma.  It follows that if $p$ decides all the membership facts about $\tau$, then $\tau$ must be in $L_\alpha$.